# EPEL & RPM Fusion for Servers?

Tags: centos, fedora, epel

Has anyone found EPEL & RPM Fusion to be stable enough for production servers?
Currently running CentOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPEL should certainly be fine - I don't use RPM Fusion.

However I recommend using the [yum priority](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) plugin to "protect" your core rpms. As the docs say, *"give at least the CentOS base and update repositories a very high priority".*

Comment: I use byobu from EPEL on every RHEL server I admin.  I think I've used a couple other packages, too, when the need arose.  It's never been a problem.

Comment: I saw the presentation of byobu @ SCALE 9x and have been using it since.  Thanks James